# How to pass data from page to page in Thymeleaf based spring boot application

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am developing application in Spring boot and i am using Thymeleaf as a template engine. Its like a Ordering application where user selects option on Page 1, Page 2  and so on and at last page i have to save all the previously user selected options to DB.

Can anyone suggest what will be the best design approach to pass data from one page to another should i need to use session ? I have Model objects defined for each page and i am passing to and from data using these model object .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did something like below

```
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class Cart
{
   // simple POJO fields
}
```

and then use this inside the Controller i want

```
@Scope("request")
public class SessionController
{
   @Autowired
   private Cart cart;

   @RequestMapping("/addToCart")
   public String addToCart(@RequestParam("id") int id)
   {
       // 
   } 
}
```

since the scope of cart is session so i can use this model object to whichever controller i want  put the value in cart object get the value from it wherever i want.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend completing this short tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/gs/handling-form-submission/). It illustrates how model attributes can be sent from a client page to the server as well as from the server to the client page.

Once the model is populated to its final state, the model can correspond to a table in your database as is illustrated in this tutorial (https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-mysql/) via Hibernate and the @Entity class.

Cheers!

Comment: @ jeremycoulter Thanks for the response . Your answer is good for single request i.e for one round trip to server and  client but i need to retain the data for multiple round trip in Struts based application we have option either to save it to session or make the scope of form as session , do we have similar option in Thymeleaf .

Comment: Yes, the model can continue to be passed from page to page and updated on each submit. You can also store data returned data in hidden form elements (i.e. <input type="hidden" th:field="*{lcboNumber}">) and pass it back to the model upon next submit.

If security is a priority though, Spring Web Flows are used in Spring MVC and are an excellent approach (https://www.baeldung.com/spring-web-flow).

Answer (score -1):

Sessions work great as well. Cheers!